# How to upload multiple files using Jquery/Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I m trying to upload two different files using Jquery and Ajax along with a text box.

However I can able to upload a single file and textbox using the code I have, but when I try to add another input type file, it breaks and doesn't upload any.

**The code for single input type file I have: (upload fine)**

***test.php***

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
    <div class='preview'><p class="temp"></p></div>
    <div >
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" />
        <input type="file" id="image" name="image" />
        <input type="file" id="image" name="image2" />
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Upload" id="but_upload">
    </div>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#but_upload").click(function(){
            var fd = new FormData();
            var files = $('#image')[0].files;
            var title = $("#title").val();
            
                fd.append('image',files[0]);
                fd.append('title',title);

                $.ajax({
                    url:'test2.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:fd,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success:function(response){
                        if(response != 0){
                            $(".temp").html(response);
                            $('.preview').show();
                        }else{
                            alert('File not uploaded');
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

***test2.php***

```
<?php

   /* Getting file name */
   $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   $title = $_POST['title'];

   /* Location */
   $location = "images-main/post-images/".$filename;
   $imageFileType = pathinfo($location,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $imageFileType = strtolower($imageFileType);

   /* Valid extensions */
   $valid_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png");

   $response = 0;
   /* Check file extension */
   if(in_array(strtolower($imageFileType), $valid_extensions)) {
      /* Upload file */
      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$location)){
          
         $response = $title;
         
      }
   }

   echo $response;
   exit;
```

**The code for multiple input type file I have: (doesn't upload anything)**

***test.php***

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
    <div class='preview'><p class="temp"></p></div>
    <div >
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" />
        <input type="file" id="image" name="image" />
        <input type="file" id="image" name="image2" />
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Upload" id="but_upload">
    </div>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#but_upload").click(function(){
            var fd = new FormData();
            var files = $('#image')[0].files;
            var filess = $('#image')[1].filess;
            var title = $("#title").val();
            
                fd.append('image',files[0]);
                fd.append('image2',filess[0]);
                fd.append('title',title);

                $.ajax({
                    url:'test2.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:fd,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success:function(response){
                        if(response != 0){
                            $(".temp").html(response);
                            $('.preview').show();
                        }else{
                            alert('File not uploaded');
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

***test2.php***

```
<?php

   /* Getting file name */
   $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   $filename2 = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
   $title = $_POST['title'];

   /* Location */
   $location = "images-main/post-images/".$filename;
   $location2 = "images-main/post-images/".$filename2;
   $imageFileType = pathinfo($location,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $imageFileType = strtolower($imageFileType);

   /* Valid extensions */
   $valid_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png");

   $response = 0;
   /* Check file extension */
   if(in_array(strtolower($imageFileType), $valid_extensions)) {
      /* Upload file */
      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$location)){
         if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'],$location2)){
          
         $response = $title;
         
         }
      }
   }

   echo $response;
   exit;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: IDs must be unique within an HTML document. You used `id="image"` on both the file input fields, but you won’t be able to access the second one _via_ this ID.

Comment: Please see [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/why-shouldnt-i-assume-i-know-who-downvoted-my-post) Also [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin) and finally [Getting to Know Stack Overflow's Voting Culture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251487) might be helpful

Answer (score -1):

This works fine. Thanks to @CBroe:

Here what did the trick.

**test.php**

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
    <div class='preview'><p class="temp"></p></div>
    <div >
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" />
        <input type="file" id="image" name="image" />
        <input type="file" id="video" name="video" />
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Upload" id="but_upload">
    </div>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#but_upload").click(function(){
            var fd = new FormData();
            var files = $('#image')[0].files;
            var filess = $('#video')[0].files;
            var title = $("#title").val();
            
                fd.append('image',files[0]);
                fd.append('video',filess[0]);
                fd.append('title',title);

                $.ajax({
                    url:'test2.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:fd,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success:function(response){
                        if(response != 0){
                            $(".temp").html(response);
                            $('.preview').show();
                        }else{
                            alert('File not uploaded');
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php

   /* Getting file name */
   $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   $filename2 = $_FILES['video']['name'];
   $title = $_POST['title'];

   /* Location */
   $location = "images-main/post-images/".$filename;
   $imageFileType = pathinfo($location,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $imageFileType = strtolower($imageFileType);
   
   $location2 = "images-main/post-images/".$filename2;
   $imageFileType2 = pathinfo($location2,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $imageFileType2 = strtolower($imageFileType2);

   /* Valid extensions */
   $valid_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png");

   $response = 0;
      /* Upload file */
      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'],$location2)){
            $response = $title;
        }
      
      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$location)){
            $response = $title;
      }

   echo $response;
   exit;
```